# WCF REST service - How to decompress the form data using gzip?

Tags: wcf, rest, gzip, compression

We have a WCF-REST service, the client is sending the data with Content Encoding = gzip and compressing the data in gzip format. However, we are unable to decompress the form data from the request received in the WCF service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, one of my collage found the answer, Thanks Sandesh and team!!!

You need to add the IHttpModule that intercepts every HTTP request and decompress the data

```
/// <summary>
    /// This class Handles various pre-conditions which has to performed before processing the HTTP request.
    /// @author XXXXX
    /// </summary>
    public class PreRequestHandler : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication httpContext)
        {
            httpContext.BeginRequest += DecompressReceivedRequest;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decompresses the HTTP request before processing it.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void DecompressReceivedRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication httpApp = (HttpApplication)sender;

            if ("gzip" == httpApp.Request.Headers["Content-Encoding"])
            {
                httpApp.Request.Filter = new GZipStream(httpApp.Request.Filter, CompressionMode.Decompress);
            }

        }
    }
```

Also, needs to add the following entry in the web.config file

```
  <!-- Configuration setting to add Custom Http Module to handle various pre-conditions which has to performed before processing the HTTP request.-->
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="PreRequestHandler" type="Your service class.PreRequestHandler"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: See another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548220/android-compressed-requests-to-wcf-rest-service-in-iis?rq=1